# How do I restrict a cell value to a maximum based on another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm creating a dashboard in excel and I'm trying to put together metrics.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I'm giving +1 for each `yes`, 0 for a `no` and -1 if Column G is a `no`. Giving a maximum potential score of 6.

**The requirement I'm struggling with is this:**

1. If column D is `no` the score cannot exceed 3
2. If column E is `no` the score cannot exceed 4

My total is in colum `H` and I've tried to use this as a limiter but all that does is set the cell value to either 3 or whatever the value in column H is: `=IF(D3="No",MAX(3),H1)`

**Is there a way to apply a limiter like this into excel or am I asking too much?**

In the above examples this is what I want the answers to be: `x=4`, `y=4`, `z=3`

Comment: will update, G is the -1 not F

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
=MIN(IF(D1="No",3,7),IF(E1="No",4,7),COUNTIF(B1:G1,"Yes")-(G1="No"))
```

[image]

Comment: Can't believe you solved that so quickly. Thanks @Scott, if you've got time could you explain this a little please? I'm not sure what the 7s are doing

Comment: The `7`s ensure that one of the other two satisfy the MIN(),  Since the max number of `Yes`es is 6, it will never be `7`.  They could just as easily been `999999`, it would never be returned as the last condition will return a number between `-1` and `6`